# jQuery Form Validation issue for Drupal 7 custom module

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have inherited a Drupal 7 site with a few very ugly custom modules that form a workflow through the site. One of the modules presents a form to the user. This form is dynamically created. The form is working fine and the data submission is working fine. The fields on the form have no validation at all and I must get some validation working urgently on this form. I would be happy if I could just get the field required validation working.

I have been doing a lot of reading about `jQuery.validate.min.js`, so much I am totally confused, and I can see the following scripts in the head of the page

```
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
jquery.validate.min.js
Note the site is using jQuery update to set the jQuery version to 1.10.2
```

The code for the form is as follows

```
<form class="details-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="details-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">

  <div class="return-block-2">
    <div class="enquire-form-wrapper form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--name webform-container-inline">
      <label>Postal Code<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input class="enquire-form-name form-control form-text return_postal" id="return_postal" type="text" value="" size="60" maxlength="128">
    </div>
    <div class="enquire-form-wrapper form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--name webform-container-inline">
      <label>Building number<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input class="enquire-form-name form-control form-text return-building" id="return-building" type="text" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" >
    </div>
    <div class="enquire-form-wrapper form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--name webform-container-inline">
      <label>Street name<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input class="enquire-form-name form-control form-text  return-street" id="return-street" type="text" value="" size="60" maxlength="128"  >
    </div>
    <div class="enquire-form-wrapper form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--name webform-container-inline">
      <label>Unit no.<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input class="enquire-form-name form-control form-text return-unit" id="return-unit" type="text" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" >
    </div>
    <div class="enquire-form-wrapper form-item webform-component webform-component-checkboxes webform-component--acknowlegment">
     <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-submitted-acknowlegment">Acknowlegment <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <div id="edit-submitted-acknowlegment" class="form-checkboxes enquire-form-check checkbox-circle"><div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-acknowlegment-check form-item checkbox">
          <input class="enquire-form-check checkbox-circle form-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-submitted-acknowlegment-1" name="submitted[acknowlegment][check]" value="check" >  <label for="edit-submitted-acknowlegment-1">I acknowledge and accept the <a href="/drupal/privacy_policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>, <a href="/drupal/terms_of_use" target="_blank">Website Terms of Use</a>, and </a><a href="/drupal/popstation-terms-conditions" target="_blank">POPStation T&amp;C.</a></label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default details-submit" >Next</button>
```

There is a javascript block below the html content and it has the following at the top

```
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   debug: true,
    success: "valid"
 });
  jQuery( "#details-form" ).validate({
    rules: {
     return_postal: {
    required: true
  }
}
});
```

There is then a document ready block that looks like this

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

});
```

This block takes care of adding and removing some classes with jQuery. It also takes care of a couple of ajax calls to the backend and parsing the json returned from the backend. All this works fine.

Finally there is the submit for the form

```
(jQuery)(".details-submit").click(function(){

    });
```

The submit does an ajax call to the backend and submits the form data in this call. Id the ajax call succeeds the JSON response is parsed and some of the response is written to a cookie. If all this succeeded there is a page redirect with a `window.location()` call. Again all this is working fine even though it is ugly.

As you should see there has been an attempt to add validation on the first field in the form, the id is return_postal. The validation does not appear to do anything. I can not see any evidence of the validation doing anything in the Firebug console.

I am not sure that the validation call is where it should be but I am not sure if it is even written correctly. I am also not sure if the validation should take place in the details-submit function rather than before the document-ready function.

I would appreciate any advice on fixing up the mess I have, in particular getting the validation working.